# Problem in selecting multiple items in Listbox.SelectionMode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpart and I want to select mulitple items in a listbox,pretty easy.I am using webcontrols namespace.So I am declaring listbox as
ListBox lBox = new ListBox();
lBox.ID="lbox";
lBox.SelectionMode="Multiple";

But it is not accepting that . The error I m getting is cannot convert string type to listbox selection sth..

If anyone is having any idea where I m getting wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: The compiler is telling you that the property `SelectionMode` is not a string, but you are attempting to assign it a string value. If you're not sure what type to assign, look up the property using MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Programmatically Select Multiple Items](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/programmatically-select-multiple-items.html)

```
<div>    
   <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="One" />
      <asp:ListItem Value="Two" /> 
      <asp:ListItem Value="Three" />    
      <asp:ListItem Value="Four" /> 
      <asp:ListItem Value="Five" />  
  </asp:ListBox></div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListBox1.SelectionMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListSelectionMode.Multiple;    
   for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)    
   {
      // Select the first, third and fifth items in the listbox
      if(i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4)        
      {
         ListBox1.Items[i].Selected = true; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: yah thats what I was looking for I tried earlier 
lBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple; but in this case I was getting the error as it SelectionMode.Multiple needs System.Windows.Forms namsespace but now its fine. Thanks  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
lBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ListBox l = new ListBox();
l.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
```